# Want to find and print multiple instances of a letter in an input (very new)

Tags: python, input, tuples

At the moment it just prints which values occur, (eg, aoo prints `[a,o]`). Want to know how to alter the code so that it prints every time the value occurs (eg, `[a,o,o]`).

```
vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
word_list = []
while True:
word = str(input("Enter a word: "))
    for i in range (len(vowels)):
        if vowels[i] in word:
            word_list.append(vowels[i])
    print("Vowels in this word: ", word_list)
```

Comment: Looks like homework. Please try to formulate the algorithm you have in mind in plain English. If you still struggle with pyhon, we are glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over the vowels, iterate over the letters in the input:

```
for letter in word:
    if letter in vowels:
        word_list.append(letter)
```

If you want more compact code, you can use a list comprehension:

```
word_list = [letter for letter in word if letter in vowels]
```